# How to send simple data from `secondpage` to `mainpage` (stateful to stateful)

Tags: flutter, stateful

i found a lot of solution passing data between ***stateless*** and ***stateful*** widget, but not between ***two stateful widgets***

***EDIT:*** i edited the code to show more details

MainPage

```js
class MainPage extends StatefulWidget {
  final String name;
  MainPage({Key key, this.name}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _MainPageState createState() => _MainPageState();
}

class _MainPageState extends State<MainPage> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(      
      body: Center(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: <Widget>[
            Text("Text from 2nd page -> "), //should return "Text from 2nd page -> BATMAN"
            FloatingActionButton(
              child: Icon(Icons.android),
              onPressed: (){
                Navigator.push(context, MaterialPageRoute(
                    builder: (context) => SecondPage()
                ));
              },
            ),
            
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

[image: MainPage screenshot]

SecondPage:

```js
class SecondPage extends StatefulWidget {
  SecondPage({Key key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _SecondPageState createState() => _SecondPageState();
}

class _SecondPageState extends State<SecondPage> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      ...
      
      Text("I choose ${_selectedMethod.name}"), // this returned "I choose BATMAN"
      
    ...
  }
```

[image: SecondPage screenshot]

So basically i want to pass `${_selectedMethod.name}` from 2ndPage to MainPage. sorry im so bad at explaining :(

Comment: How does both pages connect to each other? You navigate from one to another by using Navigator.push()? Or e.g. are they tabs from a higher page? What variable contains the information you want to pass between them? Please edit your question to include these details.

Comment: With Navigator MaterialPageRoute you create your second stateful and pass the values as final values to consume.

Comment: @Naslausky sorry, i edited my question

Comment: What I understood from your question is,
   you are clicking the android button in MainPage and it goes to SecondPage
   then you're pressing back , it comes to Mainpage with batman string right?

Comment: @BalajiRamadoss yes, but it doesnt need to pop back to mainpage. i want it just to stay at secondpage, until i pres the back button

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass variables back to a previous Page in the Navigator stack by sending it through the `.pop()` method and expecting them in the previous page with the `.then()` method:

```
class MainPage60643815 extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MainPage60643815State createState() => _MainPage60643815State();
}

class _MainPage60643815State extends State<MainPage60643815> {
  String displayTextFromSecondPage = '';

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Center(
      child: Column(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
        children: <Widget>[
          Row(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
            children: <Widget>[
              Text('Test from second page: '),
              Text(displayTextFromSecondPage),
            ],
          ),
          RaisedButton(
            onPressed: goToSecondPage,
            child: Text('Go to 2nd Page'),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }

  void goToSecondPage(){
    Navigator.of(context).push(MaterialPageRoute(
      builder: (context) {
        return SecondPage60643815(text: displayTextFromSecondPage);
      }
    )).then((valueFromSecondPage){
      setState(() {
        displayTextFromSecondPage = valueFromSecondPage;
      });
    });
  }
}

class SecondPage60643815 extends StatefulWidget {
  final String text;

  SecondPage60643815({this.text});

  @override
  _SecondPage60643815State createState() => _SecondPage60643815State();
}

class _SecondPage60643815State extends State<SecondPage60643815> {
  TextEditingController _textEditingController;

  @override
  void initState() {
    _textEditingController = TextEditingController(
      text: widget.text,
    );
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        leading: IconButton(
          icon: Icon(Icons.arrow_back),
          onPressed: goToFirstPage,
        ),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
          child: Column(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
            children: <Widget>[
              TextFormField(
                controller: _textEditingController,
                autofocus: true,
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  void goToFirstPage(){
    Navigator.of(context).pop(_textEditingController.text);
  }
}
```

Comment: my original question is not very clear. i edited my question with images

Comment: @Domi I've updated my response to do what you asked.

Comment: thank you, but i want it just to stay at secondpage without pop back to main, until i press the back button

Comment: What do you mean, you want to use the back button from the AppBar instead of a normal button?

Comment: I've modified the code to have the back button on the `AppBar` to send the data back to the Main Page.

Comment: it works! but when i switch back to secondpage the new word i entered is reseted back to batman. how do i keep the new word?

Comment: That's because I had it as default on the TextEditingController. You can just the first technique and pass it again to the 2nd page. I'll edit the code to show you how.

Comment: I have now updated the code to have all the functionality you mentioned. If this answers your question, please don't forget to mark the answer as correct. Also, please consider upvoting for relevance.

Answer (score 0):

I assume that you have a *SecondPage*-Widget. So you can do something like:

```
class _MainPageState extends State<MainPage> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      child: SecondPage('BATMAN'),
    );
  }
}
```

This might print the desired "BATMAT" Text.

**EDIT**

This might be your *SecondPage* Widget:

```
class SecondPage extends StatefulWidget {
  final String selection;

  SecondPage(this.selection);

  @override
  _SecondPageState createState() => _SecondPageState();
}

class _SecondPageState extends State<SecondPage> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
       child: Text(widget.selection),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: i have SecondPage as stateful widget. i cant call it like normal widget

Comment: You can of course put your stateful widget every where you need. Your stateful widget might have something like the following structure:

I added the Second Page Widget example to my answer

You can now use it like described above (`SecondPage()`)